# shell how to inhibit ssh yes or no input for Are you sure you want to continue connecting

Tags: linux, ssh, shell

In a shell script, it ssh to a server cluster, which includes dozens of servers. But some new servers do not run commands properly. I believe it is ssh yes or no problem. So I would like to have ssh use `'yes'` automatically for ssh a new server. like `yum -y install`.

```
sshpass -p "$pass" ssh root@host "command"
sshpass -p "$pass" scp /local/file root@host:$directory/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be because `StrictHostKeyChecking` option is set to `ask`. It may not be set explicitly, `ask` is the default value.

From [`man 5 ssh_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config):

> `StrictHostKeyChecking`
>   If this flag is set to `yes`, `ssh(1)` will never automatically add host keys to the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file, and refuses to connect to hosts whose host key has changed. This provides maximum protection against trojan horse attacks, though it can be annoying when the `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` file is poorly maintained or when connections to new hosts are frequently made. This option forces the user to manually add all new hosts. If this flag is set to `no`, ssh will automatically add new host keys to the user known hosts files. If this flag is set to `ask`, new host keys will be added to the user known host files only after the user has confirmed that is what they really want to do, and ssh will refuse to connect to hosts whose host key has changed. The host keys of known hosts will be verified automatically in all cases. The argument must be `yes`, `no`, or `ask`. The default is `ask`.

Looks like you would like to set the option to `no`. In `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` the line would be:

```
StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

Or you can override the option during `ssh` or `scp` invocation by passing `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to the tool, e.g:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@host "command"
scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no /local/file root@host:"$directory"/
```

Note there is also `VerifyHostKeyDNS` option with the default value `ask`. Refer to the manual. If you need to change it, the solution is similar.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one :

`ssh-keyscan -t ecdsa serverName`

it will add the key to `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You could improve it by adding a bit more detail such as: where the command should be run, as what user it should run, and what the effect is of adding the key to `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.